# What is the proper way to build a golang application for an older Mac OS version?

Tags: macos, go, build, cgo

I'm building a go app which also uses cgo on Mac OS Catalina and would like the binaries to be able to run on previous Mac OS versions.

What is the proper way to do this and where is it documented.
I'm having a hard time finding information on how to do this.

So far i tried:

- go help build
- go help c
- go doc cmd/cgo
- man clang
- googling various permutations of my question
- building with

  CGO_CFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=10.12" CGO_LDFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=10.12" go build -o myapp

This yields

```
otool -l myapp | grep -A3 MIN
      cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX
  cmdsize 16
  version 10.12
      sdk 10.15.6
```

Ultimately it complains when trying to run on Mojave

> The application requires macOS 10.15 or later

Comment: What did you try and what didn't  work out exactly?

Comment: Update my post.

Comment: Did you try with-macosx-sdk=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk You may need to gather the old SDK files from previous MacOS versions with XCode.

Comment: What version of Go are you using?

Comment: The last version of Go to support macOS 10.10 was Go 1.12: https://golang.org/doc/go1.12#darwin

Comment: @Adrian Thanks for the tip. I'm running go 1.14. But adjusting the min version to 10.12 makes no change.

Answer (score 4):

In the absence of a proper answer this is what i ended up with:

```
CGO_CFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=10.12" CGO_LDFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=10.12" go build -o myapp
```

This does the trick for running on mac 10.14.
The

> otool -l

stuff, if anything, makes things confusing and has apparently no relevance in this regard.